# How to compile standalone app in matlab with vpasolve

Tags: matlab

I have the next matlab's code:

```
function [Y1] = roots_2021a(q)
syms r
Y=airy(1,-r)-q*airy(-r);
x=0:0.1:20;
y=double(subs(Y,r,x));
d=diff(y>0);
k=num2cell(find(d~=0)+1);
X=double(cellfun(@(z)vpasolve(Y==0,r,x(z)),k));
Y1 = unique(X*exp(1j*pi/3));
end
```

in matlab code works perfectly, but when i compile it in standaolne app i have the next error:

**"syms, subs, vpasolve" are excluded from packaging for the MATLAB Runtime environment according to the MATLAB Compiler license. Either remove the file or function from your code, or use the MATLAB function "isdeployed" to ensure the function is not invoked in the deployed component.**

What I did: using matlabFunction, I obtained an expression for `y`, then substituting `q` into it, I obtained them numerically. After that I could find points on the X axis where y > 0. But then how to substitute all this into vpasolve and get an expression for it - I don't understand....

code for y expression:

```
syms r q
Y=airy(1,-r)-q*airy(-r);
x=0:0.1:20;
y=subs(Y,r,x);
f = matlabFunction(y)
```

but how to get the same for vpasolve?

Comment: your code does not have any error, can you please describe what are the expected results against what you currently get?

Comment: in matlab code works perfectly, but when i compile it in standaolne app i have the next error: "syms, subs, vpasolve" are excluded from packaging for the MATLAB Runtime environment according to the MATLAB Compiler license. Either remove the file or function from your code, or use the MATLAB function "isdeployed" to ensure the function is not invoked in the deployed component.

Comment: please include this in the question body to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Walter Robertson in Mathworks Forum](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/525626-eliminating-the-warnings-while-creating-standalone-application-in-matlab-app-designer):

> Nothing in the Symbolic Toolbox can be compiled into an exe or
> application, and it also cannot have code generated using MATLAB
> Coder.

The official solution is to generate a Matlab function from the symbolic expression and use that to create the standalone app. You can find the documentation here: [Deploy Generated MATLAB Functions from Symbolic Expressions with MATLAB Compiler](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/deploy-generated-matlab-function-from-symbolic-expression.html)

Comment: yeah, i did that for y expression, but i don't know how to change the code to get the same result as in matlab. i updated question body

Answer (score -1):

```
function Y1 = modified(q)
Y = @(r) airy(1,-r)-q*airy(-r);
x = 0:0.1:20;
y = Y(x);
d = diff(y>0);
k = find(d~=0)+1;
X = arrayfun(@(in) fsolve(@(r) Y(r), in), x(k));
Y1 = unique(X*exp(1j*pi/3));
end
```